# On-demand Pods for a training platform

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, traefik, isolation, ctf

I'm trying to create a training/labs platform that would allow anyone to have an isolated pod/container to connect to and play with it. I was initially planning to do it in two steps:

- Have the user request a new instance into a "Manager", which will create a new pod and new random subdomain service using Traefik to redirect to the pod. `[RANDOM UUID].challenge1.platform.com`
- The user can freely connect to the subdomain and the Load Balancer will redirect to the isolated pod.

However, previous approach had some problems:

- If I want to deploy a challenge witch exposes TCP ports there is no way for me to redirect to the pod by using domains, as TCP is not domain aware. To do so, I should give the user a unique IP instead of a domain (which removes the purpose of having a Load Balancer/Proxy). [If there is no other way to achieve it I would have to stick to this]
- Only a single HTTP port can be exposed. If I want more ports to be exposed I had to create extra rules that would either use sub-subdomain or URI/paths.`port[x].[RANDOM UUID].challenge1.platform.com` or `[RANDOM UUID].challenge1.platform.com/service[x]`

To solve previous problems I decided to have a "proxy" container. This container should listen into all the training required ports and redirect based on the request IP to a newly deployed pod for each request IP. This manager will be exposed under `challenge1.platform.com` and all users will be connecting to the same domain.

This approach would require me to write a custom "proxy" container that will forward the traffic to the desired pod. So I should keep track using a mapping of `IP -> pod`. The new pod/instance should either be deployed by every single new IP request or by manually triggering a endpoint on the proxy/manager such as `POST` request on `/new`.

> The manager will be periodically checking for "old" pods and killing them to clean resources. I still need to think in the way that I will notify the end-user that their pod is expiring or will be killed in x seconds.

I'm quite new in K8s world and I would like to know if there is any other better way to approach my problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've accomplished this by mixing Docker with OVS, Guacamole, and some custom CGI scripts.  Short version: on-demand desktops and private architectures for labs.  I'm looking at converting the rig to K8S.  From what I can tell, the desktops would be more or less static, with the lab architectures being more-or-less on demand (i.e., selectable from a menu).